# Safe combination for your heritage

Tags: cipher

Phillip, a 68 years old man, was near the end of his life.

Before passing away, he decided to hand to his daughter a piece of paper with the following:

```
48 7A 2D 38 8B
```

On the back, there was the following text:

```
DEATH, what unpleasant surprise.
While I'm gone, enjoy life and smile.
You can find my safe beneath me.
The key combination is in the front.
Give your son the life I never had.
1000 words can't describe how much I love you.
I wish everything was this basic.
```

(I know, it isn't the best text ever.)

The safe has a keyboard with numbers from 0 to 9, arranged like the image below:

[image: Lock buttons]

(This is the best photo I could find, thank you [Google](http://google.com/), [Original image](http://www.time-master.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/product_full/imagecache/product_full/lp-basic-black-keypad-web.jpg)).

Since she didn't understand the message, she asked you for help to open the safe.

What is the safe combination?

---

**Edit**:

I forgot to mention something VERY important:

The safe combination is only 5 numbers!

No more, no less.

**Edit 2**:

The answer is also a word.

The word is spelled using the above keyboard.

Each number is 1 letter.

Example: The word 'short' would be the key '84788'.

Comment: Does "beneath me" have some special meaning, or does it just mean he kept the safe under his bed?

Comment: @randal'thor It means it is under the bed. I will be a good guy and say: the position of the safe has nothing to do with it. It's just filler.

Comment: Maybe DEATH in capitals is just a tribute to the recently deceased Terry Pratchett, whose character Death always talks in capitals?

Comment: @randal'thor Who?

Comment: [Terry Pratchett](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terry_Pratchett): "[a] hallmark of his writing was the use of capitalised dialogue without quotation marks, used to indicate the character of Death communicating telepathically into a character's mind." He died yesterday. Never mind, it must be just a coincidence!

Comment: @randal'thor I've never heard of him. But thank you for sharing the link. No, the capitalization was on purpose, but wasn't for that purpose.

Comment: Whenever I see a problem like this, I think that brute-forcing is a clever (as in loophole-y) way to solve the problem. If you only need to enter 5 digits, you are guaranteed to crack the safe in 100,000 tries, which might not take very long when you consider how valuable the safe's contents are likely to be. But of course, this isn't a satisfying solution to the puzzle.

Comment: @Kevin That reminds me that I should have set a limit of tries But it is a viable option, but each try takes around 15 seconds, increasing the time a little as you move on.

Comment: BAH! The "combination" is the grinder wheel.

Comment: Damn, was hoping someone else would have solved this by now...!

Comment: I just noticed that the keys for D-E-A-T-H resemble a Glider in Conways Game of Life, maybe that is relevant? After all, life is the opposite of death and the word "life" is used twice in the riddle. I just do not know what to do with that...

Answer (score 4):

Another try:

> 48 7A 2D 38 8B

Interpreting each of these five couplets as a

> number written in hexadecimal (base 16),

we get

> 72 122 45 56 139.

---

I'm not sure what to do with this, but maybe

> divide by powers of 2, 1, 3, 8, 4 respectively (these being the digits corresponding to D, E, A, T, H on the keypad - thanks **Ryan Durrant** for this idea!)

to get

> **9 122 5 7 139**

(OK, this doesn't quite work for the 2nd and 5th digits.)

Another idea:

> take digit sums, and keep doing this until each number is reduced to a single digit. So $72\rightarrow9,122\rightarrow5,45\rightarrow9,56\rightarrow11\rightarrow2,139\rightarrow13\rightarrow4$,

giving the answer as **95924**. I can't see what word this could correspond to though!

Comment: That key is incorrect, but I tell you that you are SO close to get it! You can read my comment on @RyanDurrant's answer for a clue. But you are REALLY close.

Comment: There is also something that I left behind: The combination is a word. But I've upvoted this answer too.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I've incorporated Ryan's idea. I know it's not right yet, but am I on the right track?

Comment: Almost. But '9 122 5 7 138' is.... Many numbers. The answer is only 5 numbers. But you are getting dangerously close.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Another edit. I keep thinking that "1000" in the question should be used somehow...

Comment: Well, the `1000` is a clue. I can say that one. I won't say much more about it. But the other idea is running away from it.

Comment: I suspect that all the first letters in the poem are relevant, because it's very stilted (Sorry Ismael).  That implies it was written to convey something specific, rather than being free-form.

Comment: @Bobson I said it before, and I will repeat: it was on purpose. The casing of the letters is important. The word is an important clue. So, you don't have to be sorry.

Comment: @rand al'thor something along the lines of "A picture is worth 1000 words"?

Answer (score 4):

The code is

> 1 6 7 4 1 
>
>  A L P H A

We know that the numbers and letters turn into

> The ASCII codes "Hz-8u"

This can be decoded as

> A frequency of 8 hertz, also known as Alpha waves

We can support this further with the following lines:

DEATH - What an unpleasant surprise

> If you were exposed to this frequency, it would liquefy your brain. Doesn't sound like fun!

When I'm gone, enjoy life and smile

> The Alpha frequencies emitted by your brain, however, are associated with relaxation

You can find my safe beneath me

> I'm guessing it was in the floor or something?

The key combination is in the front

> Alpha is the first letter of the greek alphabet

Give your son the life I never had

> Uhhh... red herring?

1000 words can't describe now much I love you

> MRIs (images, pictures of your brain) use frequencies 1-100, which this is one. Obviously you're not exposed to the EXACT resonant frequency of your skull for very long, because liquefying your brain is generally bad and will get the hospital sued.

I wish everything was this basic

> Pretty much all children are taught about frequencies as part of their basic education.

Comment: In my opinion, you are escaping a little. But I do liked your answer! I had no idea that alpha waves could liquify our brain... That REALLY isn't fun!

Comment: So, the Hz in the ASCII (that you've already confirmed is correct)... am I on the right track that it's frequency related?

Comment: No, it isnt frequency related. The `H` was an accident. I didn't wanted it to be an `H`, but I let it stay anyway.

Comment: Oh - well that certainly changes things!

Answer (score 3):

When I look at this question, I start to think of something...

> is it ASCII?

1) If the numbers are in hex, we find that 8B doesn't correspond to any letter. You will actually get H, z, -, 8, ü. Not fun.

> so maybe it's base 14 (A,B,C,D)

We change the numbers to that

> and we get 64, 108, 41, 50, 123. In ASCII, this is @, l, ), 2, {, which is very wrong.

2) Maybe

> it's related to DEATH. The ASCII code will be 68, 69, 65, 84, 72 (in decimal). 68 is also the age of Phllip when he died!

But what do we do with it?

3) The dead guy actually said :

> "I wish everything was this basic."

BASIC

> is a programming language

4) Then, we see that

> BASIC is technological and ASCII is also technological.

However,

> ASCII is more heavily represented in this puzzle, so I think the answer is 18255.

A lot of things actually don't make sense but that's all I can do.

---

**Edit**

After Ismael Miguel gave me some comments, I'll continue trying.

Here is a list of hints which have been gathered.

1*. Hz-8ü & ASCII

2*. 1000 words can't describe how much I love you --> A picture of probably a heart.

3. **DEATH --> 23184**
4. basic

5**. 4 is the first number

6**. A number repeats

7**. There is at least a 7.

8*. 72 122 45 56 139

Hints with 1 * are very close, hints with 2 * are correct.

Hint 5--> The first letter of the word is f, g, or h.

Hint 7--> The word has at least a o, p or q.

Hint 4--> Based on the comment given to my solution, basic-->21852

Also, apparently I left off my problem at one thread which was very close to the answer. 
I wonder which one it is...

By guessing, I got

> Happy --> 41770. That fits. But how is it related to the hints?

Comment: Wow, dude, you were really close! I should say "Hz-8ü" is correct. The word 'basic' is part of a clue, related to another clue given in another comment. You are correct in thinking in ASCII. The age that he died is just filler. Also the name. The word DEATH is a VERY important clue.

Answer (score 2):

This seems too obvious, but...

> 487122223882?

Interpreting each letter as what it would be on the keypad you've shown, mobile-phone style (A=1, B=2, C=22, D=222, E=3, F=4, G=44, etc.)

Comment: I forgot something very important: The key length! -.- But I will accept this one as an answer and will upvote it. (I won't mark as *the* accepted answer). It is a really nice try. And I give you credit for that.

Answer (score 2):

Is it

> 23184 - DEATH

Short, simple and sweet

Comment: No, that would be TOO much too obvious. But it is part of the process to obtain the key. I wouldn't reveal the key right in the first word. But nice try!

Comment: How does that word give that number??

Comment: @randal'thor D-2, E-3, A-1, T-8, H-4.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I don't understand where that correspondence comes from though!

Comment: @randal'thor Look at the keypay. It has letters on top of it. Imagine if you were writting on the cellphone and using t9 (word prediction) function (with a weird keyboard). If you want to spell 'death', you click on 3 3 2 8 4. But this keypad has a different letter arrangement.

Answer (score 2):

I think I have it!

```
D  E  A  T  H
```

In ASCII hex:
    44 65 61 74 68

> The key combination is in the front.

```
44 65 61 74 68
^  ^  ^  ^  ^
4  6  6  7  6
```

Take the first hexadecimal digit of each ASCII character of the word "death", and that should be your answer.

Comment: Can you please explain, in the question, how you got to that result?

Comment: "The key combination is in the front" I just took that line as literally as I could. I have a feeling this explanation was wrong, but I decided to offer it up anyway, just in case...

Comment: I must say that the first number is correct in the actual position, and there is at least 1 7. I must give you credit for that! (the downvote wasn't mine). The attempt isn't the best one, but you scared me when I read the 4.

Comment: How about the second try?

Comment: The 2nd try is a bit further, but there is a number that repeats (like the number 8).

Answer (score 2):

For starters, the key combination

> 48 7A 2D 38 8B

if treated as hexadecimal, translates to

> **72  122 45  56  139** in decimal, which is
>  **H z - 8 ï** in ASCII.

I have no idea what to do with this. Yet. Let's look at other clues.

> **DEATH** corresponds to **23184** on the keypad.

I also guess that

> "1000" and "basic"

seem to be part of the same clue, somehow.

Finally, from comments on another answer, apparently,

> the answer starts with a **4**, has at least one **7**, and some digit is doubled.

---

All told, my very best guess (at the time of writing) is that the answer is

> **41388**, for **HEART**

My reasoning is that

> "1000 words" refers to how a picture is worth more than 1000 words, which made me wonder how a picture would relate to "I love you". I tried "drawing" a heart on the keypad, then realized that DEATH and HEART share the same letters, except that the D has been changed into an R, which on the same button as 8, which is 1000 in binary.

One major flaw with this though:

> It doesn't use the key code at all.

Comment: You are so close that it hurts me! The only 'problem' is that you don't use the number 7 at all. But it is quite a nice answer. I tell you that your answer is loosly related with the 'right' answer. But I will give you credit for using the clues and for a great try.

Answer (score 0):

Based on clues I will guess on `FRONT` but nothing with baseXX, acsii or hex converting is used here.. :)